# Копирование базы данных с удаленного сервера через pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

Необходимо скопировать базу данных из удаленного сервера (мне предоставили ip, базу данных, пароль). База данных - **PostgreSQL** (ранее в ней не работал, только сегодня установил). Что необходимо прописать для того, чтобы скопировать данные. Нашел, что необходимо использовать данную команду:

```
pg_dump -U username database -f dump.sql -h 127.0.0.1 -W
```

Пример: `pg_dump -U testUser testDataBase -f dump.sql -h 127.0.0.1 -W testpassword`

Вносить данную запись необходимо в PSQL (консоль)?
Пробовал вносить уже не с тестовыми данными, но не получилось, может что-то в шаблоне тестового запроса не так?

Если у кого-то есть какая инфа относительно данного вопроса, буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Советую подробнее ознакомится с [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html), есть [русский вариант](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/app-pgdump)

Вводить нужно не в `psql`, а в терминале сразу.

Схема следующая `pg_dump [connection-option...] [option...] [dbname]`,
сначала параметры вводите, потом имя базы.

Для Вашего примера: `pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -U testUser testDataBase > testDataBase.dump`, параметр `W` можно не указывать, pg_dump запросит у Вас пароль и без параметра.